# xpath expression to force to return absent nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<matrix id="2x2withNulls">
    <row>
        <column num="1">346</column>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column num="1">444</column>
        <column num="2">56</column>
    </row>
</matrix>
```

I need to iterate over the whole matrix,  is there any way to force the expression to create a node where null?

Ideally `/matrix/row/column` someway returns the four expected nodes.

`/matrix/row/column[as many as max(foreach /matrix/column/)]`, duplicate if necessary
or
`/matrix/row/column[not(exists num where exists in other colum)-> create it]`

I can only use one expression, as the expression is a parameter for a third party application.

Perhaps there must a way to force to result column num1 repeated for the first row, so it always returns max(columns) even if they are duplicates of the last existintg column in the half empty row.

Answer (score 4):

The concept of "selecting an absent node" is an interesting one, but is likely to lead you down a false trail. As some philosopher once said of God, existence is not a predicate; you can't select all the nodes that don't exist.

The tricky bit is your statement "I can only use one expression, as the expression is a parameter for a third party application." That seems to rule out XSLT, although you've included the XSLT tag in your question. So I think it would be good to know the constraints more precisely.

I would tweak Erat's solution a little:

```
return <matrix> {
  $matrix/@*,
  for $row in $matrix/row
  return <row> {
    for $i in 1 to 2
    return ($row/column[@num=$i], <column num="{$i}"/>)[1]
  } </row>
}</matrix>
```

Comment: I decided against including that remark myself, but it's 100% true: it's pointless to add empty nodes.

Comment: Maybe there is some parallel tinking trick... at list I would like to return me as duplicates of a column as the max (see my new PS)

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating the `xml` yourself, you could start out by making sure it validates against an `xsd` that has a `sequence` with `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` set to a desired count; that would do the trick in constraining the number of nodes per se.

Read up on `xsd` `sequence` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp).

If you're getting this xml out of the 3rd-party app, but want to include empty nodes, you can use `LinqToXml` (assuming you can use C# in your project and also assuming `xDoc` is an `XDocument` containing the `xml`):

```
public void AddEmptyNodesIf(XDocument xDoc, int targetElementCount = 4)
{
    XElement e = new XElement("column");
    e.Add(new XAttribute("num", null));

    foreach (XElement row in xDoc.Elements("row"))
    {
        int lastOccurringId = int.Parse(row.Elements("column")
            .Last().Attribute("num").Value);

        while (row.Elements("column").Count() < targetElementCount)
        {
            lastOccurringId++;
            e.Attribute("num").Value = lastOccurringId.ToString();
            row.Add(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I did not test this, but even if it doesn't completely work, you get the general gist of it.

Comment: Thanks! But I have a constraint I appended in the P.S, it is a third party app and it only asks for "XPATH expresion to iterate", so I must do it with the single help of an XPATH query

Comment: @user1352530 XPath is a query language. Use it for querying only. There's no real need for (or advantage to) adding empty nodes. Whatever code is reading the xml, should be written in a way that can deal with that.

Comment: Maybe filling with duplicates (or repeated iteration over same node) for those which does not have the complete matrix?

Comment: @user1352530 Can tell me why you need empty nodes?

Comment: Can only use an XPath over them, and I would like to not change the XML (you know, company burocracy), but also I'd like to know if there is a way to avoid loading everything and parse it manually

Comment: @user1352530 but... but...but... WHAT are you doing with the xml, then? Is it printed out 200 times to wallpaper someone's office? Is it being read by some application? Is that application unable to deal with unevenly numbered child nodes? Does this application have obsessive-compulsive disorder? Why OH WHY do you NEED these empty nodes? TELL ME, oh fellow Earthling and I shall name my firstborn after you!!!

Comment: I told you, I'm just asking to know whether it exists a cleaner option (by query) before leading with all this filling logic after it. I need null values because I need to configure the matrix, and I am using an ETL so it's more tedious than pure programming

Answer (score 2):

You will have to reconstruct the result, and create new columns when necessary.

```
let $matrix :=
  <matrix id="2x2withNulls">
    <row>
      <column num="1">346</column>
    </row>
    <row>
      <column num="1">444</column>
      <column num="2">56</column>
    </row>
  </matrix>

return element matrix {
  $matrix/@*,
  for $row in $matrix/row
  return element row {
    for $i in 1 to 2
    return
      if ($row/column[@num=$i])
      then $row/column[@num=$i]
      else element column { attribute num { $i }}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have a constraint I appended in the P.S, it is a third party app and it only asks for "XPATH expresion to iterate", so I must do it with the single help of an XPATH query

Comment: You're using the [tag:xquery] tag and asked for an XPath/XQuery solution in the title, thus I posted an XQuery solution. **This cannot be done with plain XPath.** XPath can only select subtrees as result, not construct new results.

Comment: Maybe some way for selecting same node as many times given a condition like total columns for that row not=max?

Comment: I'm just guessing you're also limited to XPath 1.0. If so: no, not for arbitrary input tuples. And please fix your tagging to represent your question, tag spamming just sends lots of people here unnecessarily spending their time for answers not really fitting your problem.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I used XQuery in the past and it makes you use frequently XPATH so indeed XPATH is like a subset of XQUERY knowledge. The problem is I Should have stressed more the sentence where I explain i can only use a XPATH expression due to 3rd party constraints

Comment: You're still using the wrong [tag:xslt] tag and have XQuery in the title.